# Why does the Ruby code execution jump into another method?

Tags: ruby

I have this Ruby 3.2.2 code bug that is baffling me. Using byebug to step through the code, the execution will jump from line 70 to line 100 -- by this happens is truly baffling.

I have included the relevant code snippet here, with line number, and the value of aline in the parameter is "2022 Outdoor Journal":

```
 61   def test_for_nonentry_lines( aline )
 62
 63     if 'JANUARY FEBRUARY MARCH APRIL MAY JUNE JULY AUGUST SEPTEMBER OCTOBER NOVEMBER DECEMBER'.include? aline
 64       # If a month is detected, it means processing is between trip entries,
 65       # so set global IN_ENTRY to false:
 66         $IN_ENTRY = false
 67         return true
 68     elsif aline.include?('Outdoor Journal')
 69         $IN_ENTRY = false
 70         return true
 71     elsif aline.include?('——————')
 72         $IN_ENTRY = false
 73         return true
 74     elsif aline =~ /^\n$/ and not $IN_ENTRY
 75       # If this is a blank line but we're not writing a trip entry,
 76       # then this is a nonentry line:
 77         return true
 78     else
 79         return false
 80     end
 81   end
 82
 83   # ----------------------------------------------
 84   # is_start_of_entry
 85   #
 86   # tests current line as to whether is the start
 87   # of a new journal entry. returns boolean.
 88   # ----------------------------------------------
 89   def is_start_of_entry( aline )
 90
 91     # use a regexp to test if the passed in current line is start of a journal entry,
 92     # the pattern here is either the string "(pics)"
 93     # AND a date pattern like 1/15/22 or  1/5/22:
 94     # ELSE IF
 95     # the pattern matches this pattern: a blank line followed
 96     # by (some chars a comma)*n, a date, then a comma
 97
 98     # A line is the start of the new entry if:
 99     # - the line has a date & contains the string "(pics)"
100     if aline =~ /\d?\d\/\d?\d\/\d\d/ and aline =~ /(pics)/
101       return true
```

Code execution should 'return true' on line 70. I am using byebug to step through the code, and when it executes line 70, the program jumps to line 100....which is truly baffling.

Can supply the entire program if needed.

thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Probably some code calls this method. Grep it or try to comment it and you will see where from

Comment: I don't think that's it...

Comment: Could sure use a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the ways it happens:

```rb
require "byebug"

def test_for_nonentry_lines
  byebug
  if true
    p "from here"
  else
    false
  end
end

def is_start_of_entry arg
  p "to over there"
end

is_start_of_entry("line") if test_for_nonentry_lines
# or like this
# is_start_of_entry(
#   test_for_nonentry_lines
# )

# if test_for_nonentry_lines
#   # in this case you would actually jump here
#   is_start_of_entry("line")
# end
```

```rb
$ ruby jump.rb
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/lib/byebug/attacher.rb:14: warning: undefining the allocator of T_DATA class Byebug::ThreadsTable
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/lib/byebug/attacher.rb:14: warning: undefining the allocator of T_DATA class Byebug::Context

[1, 10] in /home/alex/code/stackoverflow/jump.rb
    1: require "byebug"
    2: 
    3: def test_for_nonentry_lines
    4:   byebug
    5:   if true
=>  6:     p "from here"
    7:   else
    8:     false
    9:   end
   10: end
(byebug) next
"from here"

[8, 17] in /home/alex/code/stackoverflow/jump.rb
    8:     false
    9:   end
   10: end
   11: 
   12: def is_start_of_entry arg
=> 13:   p "to over there"
   14: end
   15: 
   16: 
(byebug) next
"to over there"
```

If you jumped somewhere you didn't expect, look at the backtrace `bt` and you can also go `up` to take a look:

```rb
[8, 17] in /home/alex/code/stackoverflow/jump.rb
    8:     false
    9:   end
   10: end
   11: 
   12: def is_start_of_entry arg
=> 13:   p "to over there"
   14: end
   15: 
   16: is_start_of_entry(
   17:   test_for_nonentry_lines
(byebug) up

[11, 20] in /home/alex/code/stackoverflow/jump.rb
   11: 
   12: def is_start_of_entry arg
   13:   p "to over there"
   14: end
   15: 
=> 16: is_start_of_entry(
   17:   test_for_nonentry_lines
   18: )
   19:
```

Also, no colors in byebug, use `debugger` instead, which you should already have by default *https://github.com/ruby/debug*.

Comment: This is very helpful. Will check this out & report back.

Comment: I switched to debugger, which does do a better job; but it does not help explain _why_ the jump in execution occurs? There is a next statement in my code that is never executed even though it is right after the when statement...which is just baffling to me...

Comment: @rixter the jump that you show in the question happens at the `return` and into the next method, which is just fine. if you're jumping over the `when` statement that means it didn't match. but can't explain something without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was caused by the === operator used in case statements. Though I cannot prove it, the code started working when I replaced the case statements with if/then statements...